# Linking iOS simulator to VS Code

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, visual-studio, ios-simulator

So I'm trying to run a flutter project on an Xcode iPhone simulator. My main issue now is the VS Code is refusing to recognize the iPhone simulator running in the background. When I run flutter emulators in my vs code terminal to try to find the iPhone simulator, VS Code doesn't recognize it, for some reason. [error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv7bh.png) . Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2):

hit **command + shift + p**, then find **Launch Emulator** and open your created emulator. If your pc is slow then give it some times or restart vsc. let me know more if it fixed or not.